# Stock calculation to be done by given date

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Stock Calculation to be start from given date

My Sql query is sum stock values for date wise and I stored in value variable.

```
let value = [
  { place: 'Bangalore', production:16, stock: -3, date: '2021-06-26' },
  { place: 'Bangalore', production:2.5, stock: 13, date: '2021-06-27' },
  { place: 'Bangalore', production:3, stock: 15.5, date: '2021-06-28' },
  { place: 'Bangalore', production:5.5, stock: 18.5, date: '2021-06-29' },
  { place: 'Bangalore', production:4, stock: 24, date: '2021-06-30' },
  { place: 'Bangalore', production:7, stock: 28, date: '2021-07-09' },
  { place: 'Bangalore', production:9, stock: 35, date: '2021-07-10' }
]
```

I want accumulation of previous day stock+production=today stock. Its working as expected below script.
But I have to calculate if middle of date production value change.

```
value.reduce((acc, cur) => {
   const newArr = acc + cur.stock;
   cur.stock = acc;
   return newArr;
 }, 0);
console.log("value::::",value)
```

If I update any of the production value in middle of date it has to calculate stock from that date only.

eg expected results:
Suppose If edit `2021-06-29  production:5`

outcome:

```
 { place: 'Bangalore', production:16, stock: -3, date: '2021-06-26' },
  { place: 'Bangalore', production:2.5, stock: 13, date: '2021-06-27' },
  { place: 'Bangalore', production:3, stock: 15.5, date: '2021-06-28' },
  { place: 'Bangalore', production:5.5, stock: 18.5, date: '2021-06-29' },
  { place: 'Bangalore', production:4, stock: 24, date: '2021-06-30' },
  { place: 'Bangalore', production:7, stock: 28, date: '2021-07-09' },
  { place: 'Bangalore', production:9, stock: 35, date: '2021-07-10' }
```

Kindly suggest your ideas. Its greatly appreciated

```js
let value = [
  { place: 'Bangalore', production:16, stock: -3, date: '2021-06-26' },
  { place: 'Bangalore', production:2.5, stock: 13, date: '2021-06-27' },
  { place: 'Bangalore', production:3, stock: 15.5, date: '2021-06-28' },
  { place: 'Bangalore', production:5.5, stock: 18.5, date: '2021-06-29' },
  { place: 'Bangalore', production:4, stock: 24, date: '2021-06-30' },
  { place: 'Bangalore', production:7, stock: 28, date: '2021-07-09' },
  { place: 'Bangalore', production:9, stock: 35, date: '2021-07-10' }
]


value.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    const newArr = acc + cur.stock;
    cur.stock = acc;
    return newArr;
  }, 0);
console.log("value::::",value)
```

2nd example sample outcome

```js
let myarray = [5, 10, 3, 2];
    let new_array = [];  
    myarray.reduce( (prev, curr,i) =>  new_array[i] = prev + curr , 0 )
    console.log(new_array);
```

Comment: Use the SQL tag if you want an answer in SQL.  If so, also tag the database and provide the data in a *tabular* format.

Answer (score 1):

You will need an identifier for which date the stock is updated. Let's say we store it as `update: 1` in the array. Based on this identifier we can reset the previous stock value in the recursive function.

```js
let value = [
      { place: 'Bangalore', production:16, stock: -3, date: '2021-06-26' },
      { place: 'Bangalore', production:2.5, stock: 13, date: '2021-06-27' },
      { place: 'Bangalore', production:3, stock: 15.5, date: '2021-06-28' },
      { place: 'Bangalore', production:6.5, stock: 18.5, date: '2021-06-29', update: 1 },
      { place: 'Bangalore', production:4, stock: 24, date: '2021-06-30' },
      { place: 'Bangalore', production:7, stock: 28, date: '2021-07-09' },
      { place: 'Bangalore', production:9, stock: 35, date: '2021-07-10' }
    ]


    value.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        /* Reset previous stock value if current production value is changed */
        if(cur.update == 1) acc = null;
        
        let newArr;
        
        /* If not null that means either the entry is first or it has changed */
        if(acc !== null)
        {
          newArr = acc + cur.stock;
          cur.stock = acc;
        }
        else
        {
          newArr = cur.stock;
        }
        
        return newArr;
      }, null); /* Set the first value to null so that we can identify it's first */
    console.log("value::::",value)
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer But `date: '2021-06-26'` stock is -3 right its coming as 0 it should not it has to calculate previous date stock+production

Comment: What should be the stock value for 2021-06-26? I do not have previous records in sample to compare. Please share sample output for each day so that it's easy for us to understand and tweak the solution.

Comment: or else at least it has to calculate D-1 Date ie first record 26th is same values like `production:16, stock: -3`, Next day it has to calculate so on.

Comment: Updated my answer to retain first entry and newly updated entries intact.

Comment: Its helped me. Thanks